# Sending random gif with user tag inside embed message in discord py

Tags: discord.py

im trying to send a random gif with user mention inside the embed message, the user tag is fine, but the gif wont show in the embed message. Heres the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt4hv.png) of the message.

Also heres the code for the command

```html
@client.command()
async def slap(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    randomgifs = [
    discord.Embed(title = "", description = f'{ctx.author.mention} has slapped {user.mention}\n\nhttps://i.imgur.com/8KfHd8m.gif', color = ctx.author.color), 
    discord.Embed(title = "", description = f'{ctx.author.mention} has slapped {user.mention}\n\nhttps://i.imgur.com/AAUukQd.gif', color = ctx.author.color),
    discord.Embed(title = "", description = f'{ctx.author.mention} has slapped {user.mention}\n\nhttps://i.imgur.com/ZDiDDdc.gif', color = ctx.author.color),
    discord.Embed(title = "", description = f'{ctx.author.mention} has slapped {user.mention}\n\nhttps://i.imgur.com/28BGRwI.gif', color = ctx.author.color),
    discord.Embed(title = "", description = f'{ctx.author.mention} has slapped {user.mention}\n\nhttps://i.imgur.com/HqHljrw.gif', color = ctx.author.color)]
    randomitem = random.choice(randomgifs)
    await ctx.send(embed=randomitem)
```

I have seen so many question similar to this one but theres none of those answer for the random messages one and when im using their fixed code in those question, the command is not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting the link in the description of the embed won't render it. You need to set it as the [image](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.set_image).

```py
@client.command()
async def slap(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    randomgifs = [
        "https://i.imgur.com/8KfHd8m.gif",
        "https://i.imgur.com/AAUukQd.gif",
        "https://i.imgur.com/ZDiDDdc.gif",
        "https://i.imgur.com/28BGRwI.gif",
        "https://i.imgur.com/HqHljrw.gif"
    ]
    
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "",
        description = f"{ctx.author.mention} has slapped {user.mention}",
        color = ctx.author.color
    )

    randomgif = random.choice(randomgifs)
    embed.set_image(url = randomgif)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```